# Magento, Datepicker, how to disable past days, current date selection

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-ui-datepicker

Helo,
I am beginer with litle knowledge in programing please anyone hel will be grateful. just need to disabele current date and past date selection in magento dayepicker. and do not know which file to modify. here is the link to product page http://www.globetrotter.ge/sightseeing/tbilisi-walking-tour.html 
Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **minDate** options for ui-datepicker / Check the documentation of jquery-ui-datepicker http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate/